# Improve json fetching time (google geocoder api)

Tags: php, json, google-geocoder

Using Google Geocoder API, I need to get specific data i.e. lat and lng of a location with code below:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$request = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $_POST['location'])."&sensor=false",false,$context);
$json = json_decode($request, true);
```

The problem is that every fetching of json takes at least 14 seconds, everytime(which I need it to be much faster). Is there any way to optimize fetching such as to fetch only lat and lng instead of all data from Google API? Thank you.

Comment: Should not take that long. Have you tried `CURL` instead? Also why do you need the `preg_replace`, just use `urlencode($_POST['location'])`

Comment: Reacts spiffy here, indicating the problem is not in that code (at least not in the one shown). Make sure it's not a locking session problem (no session started in the real code), and then: (1) try a `wget` from the command line from that server: is it still slow? That would indicate network problems (DNS, routing, bandwidth, etc.), or maybe google throttles you due to too much use. If it isn't... then I wouldn't know what causes it ;)

Comment: I'm surprised. Look url up on network tool shows this:

    > maps.googleapis.com is an alias for googleapis.l.google.com.
    > googleapis.l.google.com has address 74.125.200.95
    > googleapis.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4003:c00::5f

By simply changing 74.125.200.95 to replace maps.googleapis.com gets me immediate response!